# Change the value of window standard variables in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a website that has the following code:

```
if(window.location.host === 'example.com'){
passToken('SECRET_TOKEN');
} else {
error();
}
```

So, I was wondering if someone can bypass this and get the function `passToken()` to work from another host.

doing `window.location.host = 'something.com'` does a redirect to that host, is it possible to change that value?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your goal, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a website that has the following code: 
```
if(window.location.host === 'example.com'){
passToken();
} else {
error();
}
So, I was wondering if someone can bypass this and get the function `passToken()` to work from another host.

Comment: Anyone can call passToken-function by just typing ***passToken();*** in the browser console. If that is a security risk, then your site has a serious problem.

Comment: @user7864052 he could copy the code and remove the if...

Comment: You got it wrong, the `passToken()` function is not defined in that file. Sorry, my bad, it's `passToken('TOKEN')`

Comment: My website passes the token to another domain `trusted.com`, the `trusted.com` domain has`passToken()` function defined then it will load the javascript file `mywebsite.com/token.js` which will have the JS code in the question.

Comment: Have a look at [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction/). Much more secure method when passing tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe it is a JS reserved word

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp